# Disabling parallax scrolling on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I'm using parallax.js to run it for my website. I want to disable parallax scrolling for mobile, but nothing I have tried works. Here's my code.

```
<div id="artwork" class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-position="-70px" data-image-src="test.jpg" style="opacity: 0" background="cover">
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="dazed-artwork" width="400">
</div>
```

and my css...

```
.parallax-window {
        min-height: 300px;
        background: transparent;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        speed: 0.8;
        positionY: 400px;
        bleed: 20px;
        overflow: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:749px) {
    .parallax-window {
        background-attachment: inherit;
  }
}
```

I've tried many other media query variations without success. Someone please help me!